# CSS manage nested flexbox width by content priority

Tags: css, flexbox

I struggling with flexbox wrapping.

I have this 2 levels list:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list list-1">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list list-2">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
    <div class="item">F</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">&#9733;</div>
</div>
```

The HTML structure can be modified if its needed.

Base on wrapper width render should fit these rules:

- mimic one list (same margin between all items);
- The **first item of all lists** have to be visible;
- but list-1 content has priority of list-2;
- items only complete item can be visible in the list;

Render example:

- `1 A X`
- `1 2 3 A X`
- `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A X`
- `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F X`

With my current achievement, I miss the priority wrapping (the both list get the same width and number of elements), and the spaces between items in both lists are not the same.

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #222;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.list div:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 2px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 45px;
  height: 26px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 4px 4px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
```

Any idea are welcome!

Answer (score 5):

You can add `flex-shrink:0` to the first list so it will never shrink and you will have your priority rule and add `min-width:0` to the other list to allow it to shrink when there isn't enough space. You should also allow the `wrap` so that you don't see half an element when it overflow.

*With your new rule there will be a wrong space with the last element.*

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 37px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #222;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  
}

/*added this*/
.list-1 {
  flex-shrink:0;
}
.list-2 {
  min-width:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
/**/
.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 45px;
  height: 26px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 4px 4px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  flex-shrink:0; /*this is also mandatory to avoid the item to shrink*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list list-1">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list list-2">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
    <div class="item">F</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">&#9733;</div>
</div>
```

Without overlfow here is a hack to hide the non needed element:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 37px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #222;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  position:relative;
  align-self: flex-start; 
}
.list::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  top:37px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:#fff;
}

/*added this*/
.list-1 {
  flex-shrink:0;
}
.list-2 {
  min-width:0;
}
/**/
.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 45px;
  height: 26px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 4px 4px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  flex-shrink:0; /*this is also mandatory to avoid the item to shrink*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="list list-1">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="list list-2">
    <div class="item">A</div>
    <div class="item">B</div>
    <div class="item">C</div>
    <div class="item">D</div>
    <div class="item">E</div>
    <div class="item">F</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">&#9733;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. It fixes part of the problem, but I cannot see half-item. The list should contains only full items (new rule added).

Comment: @ali_o_kan updated, but now there is the distance rule missing ... will try to fix it

Comment: Badly `overflow:hidden;` cannot be used because on each items we will have attached tooltips, that will be hidden too :/

Comment: @ali_o_kan you are ok with a hacky way to hide without overflow?

Comment: If its compatible IE11, definitely :p

Comment: @ali_o_kan ok have a look, the trick is to add an overlay with the same background color (white in this case)

Comment: I finally move to JS solution to resolve the number of items by group based on the container size.  Thx for your time!